# Will SDIO-mode second SD card conflict with integrated WiFi?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, sd-card, pi-zero-w

One is able to add a second SD card on RasPis by activating the SDIO interface.

However, on the Pi 3 and Pi Zero, the integrated WiFi is connected via SDIO.

Can you have both at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Results of a test with a Pi 3 A+, following instructions from [here](https://ralimtek.com/raspberry%20pi/electronics/software/raspberry_pi_secondary_sd_card/);

- Second SD card via SDIO 1-bit

  1) Second SD card appears as `/dev/mmcblk1`

  2) Integrated WiFi interface does not appear in `ifconfig`
- Second SD NOT enabled

  1) Second SD card is ignored

  2) Integrated WiFi interface appears in `ifconfig`, and is functional

No, you can't have both, they are mutually exclusive. You need to use USB if you want both a second storage device and wifi.

Comment: I am unble to test 4-bit SDIO. If someone else can do that, feel free to post the results.